# How can I study the monotonicity of a sequence containing $n$ as an angle?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I study the monotonicity of the following sequence?

$$x_{n} = \sin \frac{1}{n},$$

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that $\sin u$ is increasing on $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: why you choose specially this interval ..... may be because $1/n$ is a very small quantity.... right? but what exactly the answer that I would write?

Comment: You know that $\pi/2>1$ and so all $1/n$ lies in $[0,\pi/2]$. So when $n>n+1$, $1/n<1/(n+1)$ and since $\sin$ is (strictly) increasing in this interval so $\sin(1/n)<\sin(1/(n+1))$, hence $a_{n}$ is (strictly) decreasing.